# Typescript pattern for multiple generic methods

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Let's assume I have a class (`Person`), that has two methods that can have multiple implementations (`getFirstName` and `getSurname`). These implementations can be combined freely, to create every permutation. So if I had two implementations for each function: `A`,`B` and `a`,`b` respectively, the possible permutations are `Aa`, `Ab`, `Ba`, `Bb`. In that case, I would need four separate child classes, if I used simple inheritance.

Using C++ one could do something like the following using templates:

```
abstract class FirstName {
    public abstract getFirstName?(data: string): string | null;
}

abstract class Surname {
    public abstract getSurname?(data: string): string | null;
}

class Person<A extends FirstName, B extends Surname> implements A, B {
   constructor() {}
}


const person = new Person<FirstNameImplementation1, SurnameImplementation1>();
console.log(person.getFirstName());
```

The above does not work in Typescript. The definition of `person` should occur at compile time, and the generic types should easily be specified at the point of instantiation. Is there a way to do the above correctly in Typescript? I realise I could pass in the functions as parameters, but I assume there must be a way to do this neatly with generics.

Comment: Take a look at TypeScript mixins.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution, but I think there might be something better:

```
type GetFirstName = (data: string) => string | null;

type GetSurname = (data: string) => string | null;

class Person {
   constructor(getFirstName?: GetFirstName, getSurname?: GetSurname) {
       if (getFirstName) this.getFirstName = getFirstName;
       if (getSurname) this.getSurname = getSurname;
   }

   public getFirstName?(data: string): string | null;
   public getSurname?(data: string): string | null;
}


const person = new Person(FirstNameImplementation1);
console.log(person.getFirstName.?());
```